# Why is imagemagick-convert able to convert jpg to png when it has only jpeg as delegate

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When i execute the command, convert -version, it gives the following output.

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2019-08-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: jpeg
```

As per the above only jpeg is supported in delegates which means only jpeg can be read and written. Why is that i am able to convert to png?

`convert /tmp/val.jpg /tmp/val.png` works perfectly fine. Why?

Why are these formats called delegates and not "formats supported"?

https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php
https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28781

says only the format in delegates can be converted.

```
convert - version
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all ImageMagick delegates are image formats. Some support text (fontconfig, freetype) or colors (lcms). They are called delegates, because they are external programs that ImageMagick uses to process certain image formats or help with other tasks.

Your output is likely still JPG, but has a png suffix. You can check it from

```
convert image -format "%m" info:

or 

identify -verbose image
```

and you will see the actual format.

For example, here I convert a JPG to a fictitious ABC format.

```
convert logo.jpg logo.abc
convert logo.abc -format "%m" info:

JPEG
```

So the actual format is JPEG.

Imagemagick can write to some formats without a delegate (for example PDF), but needs a delegate (Ghostscript) to read it. However, I do not think PNG is one of those formats.

You will need to re-install or install more delegates. I recommend installing from a binary.

See [Imagemagick binaries listed here for various platforms](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

You have not said what platform you are on, but Linux distributions come with ImageMagick installed with delegates.